# How to sum a column of data without double counting - postgressql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am stumped on how to solve this issue. I have a that job runs once an hour and inserts the total number of transactions *for the last 24 hours*.  The table looks like:

| id | date | datavalue | record type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-06 00:00:00 | 1000000 | seeded data |
| 2 | 2023-10-06 23:00:00 | 150000 | job data |
| 3 | 2023-10-07 00:00:00 | 143000 | job data |
| 4 | 2023-10-07 01:00:00 | 151000 | job data |

I need a SQL query that SUMs the datavalue so that at any given time I can get the exact total number of transactions without double-counting since each record value includes much of the count in the previous record.

I am planning on seeding the column with a starting transaction count and using that as the base of the calculation but for some reason I am finding it difficult to get my head around how to get an accurate number.

Changing the job or the frequency of the job is not an option.

Thanks for any ideas!

**Updated**: Thanks for the replies and suggestions. Sorry my initial question was kind of sparse on the details. I've updated the table as well.

Id 1 is the seeded data.  Each "job data" type record contains the last 24 hours count of transactions but are inserted hourly which means each record prior to the new record already contain most of the count in the newly inserted record.

For record id 2 most of the 23 out of 24 hours of data is already included in the seeded value, leaving 1/24th of 150000 as actual uncounted transactions and I think the calc would be `150000 - (150000 * (23/24)` = 6250 uncounted transactions.)  The total transactions as of record 2 would be 1006250.

Id 3 contains an additional 143000 transactions from the last 24 hours and using the reasoning above needs to deduct the amount already included in the seeded record 1 and record 2.  `(143000 - (143000 * (11/12)` = 11917 uncounted transactions.) The total transactions as of record 3 would be 1011917. 1000000 + 6250 + 5667

After the first 24 hours of records, this reasoning would always deduct the 23 hours of records prior to it to get the running count of uncounted transactions with each new record.

Hope this makes things more clear.

Comment: `SUM` over what time period?

Comment: Given the frequency of the job I think that what you call 'double counting' is by far the best idea, with a relevant index.

Comment: Please include the expected result for this sample data.

Comment: @TheImpaler - updated my comments with expected results

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT 
    current_timestamp AS current_time, -- desired point in time
    SUM(datavalue - COALESCE(LAG(datavalue) OVER (ORDER BY date), 0)) AS total_transactions
FROM your_table
WHERE date <= current_timestamp;
```

I believe this is what you intend? A bit hard to tell from the lack of desired output, however, these are the functions used in this snippet -
LAG window function is used to retrieve the value of datavalue from the previous row in the result set, ordered by the date column, COALESCE is used to handle the first row where there is no previous row, and it defaults to 0 and finally, probably what you need, the SUM function then sums up the differences between consecutive datavalue values up to the specified point in time. If this doesn't get your desired output, I'd suggest you to update the question with the desired output so that we can work around that. Cheers!

Comment: "Failed to run sql query: aggregate function calls cannot contain window function calls" - this was a frequent result when I asked Chat GPT to write me a query.